# Restarting the GUI (GDM3) on Ubuntu via remote SSH

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, gdm

Given an Ubuntu 18.04.2LTS on a desktop computer (not headless) which haven't been restarted since at least months.

Access is only possible via some remote desktop connection (like vnc) and SSH.

Now the rdp connection was faulty, and I decided to (not so wisely) restarting the gdm3:

```
service gdm3 restart
```

But after this command, rdp is not working at all, it seems the GUI is not running.

I have no physical access to the computer, and rebooting is also not possible remotely.

How can I properly (re)start Ubuntu 18.04's default GUI from remote SSH without restarting the computer?

It would be even better to restart the GUI "at the login prompt": force logging out all users, and start as fresh as a clean startup would do.

Please note I have already activated Xorg instead of Wayland long time ago by this:

```
[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

## Update

Based on @intika's recommendation I logged in via SSH and run this:

```
$ sudo -u user bash;
$ export DISPLAY=:0;
$ startx
xauth:  file /home/user/.Xauthority does not exist

/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Comment: You have to find a way to startx (xorg) from the real console... may be with a cron job... ssh is the only way to remote control the machine ?

Comment: Yes, only SSH is working, nothing else, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe there is way to start xorg just for vlc or something similar... i don't know the exact procedure...